# Second selection based on first

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I'm trying to make two `select` queries so that second selection have to based on first. I give first table name "t1" and try to make second selection based on first but finally i get database error.

SQL

```
SELECT startpoli_i ,
       finalpoli_i ,
       prosfora ,
       comments_pro ,
       accepted ,
       onoma01 ,
       epitheto01 ,
       email01 ,
       tilefono01 ,         
       weight1 ,
       depdate1 ,
       specialservices1 ,
       comments1 ,
       username01
FROM   (offers ,registration1 ,customer)  t1
WHERE  (
              offers.string_uniq regexp concat( :str)
       AND    registration1.username01 = offers.user_i
       AND    customer.startpoli1 = offers.startpoli_i
       AND    customer.finalpoli1 = offers.finalpoli_i )
UNION
SELECT startpoli_i ,
       finalpoli_i ,
       prosfora ,
       comments_pro ,
       accepted ,
       onoma01 ,
       epitheto01 ,
       email01 ,
       tilefono01 ,          
       weight1 ,
       depdate1 ,
       specialservices1 ,
       comments1 ,
       username01
FROM   offers ,
       registration1 ,
       customer
WHERE  offers.startpoli_i = t1.startpoli_i
AND    offers.finalpoli_i = t1.finalpoli_i
```

I am pretty sure that error has to do with how i use table name t1. Any suggestion;

Comment: What's the error? Do the queries work individually? What do you mean 'based on first query?' union will merge the results.

Comment: I get no results. First query works individually.  With 'based on first query' i mean that i try to name first selection as "t1" and get second table with "offers.startpoli_i = t1.startpoli_i
AND    offers.finalpoli_i = t1.finalpoli_i     " statements where ti is involved

Comment: I am fairly certain you cannot reference one part of a UNION in another part of it. I am not even sure it could make logical sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT startpoli_i ,
       finalpoli_i ,
       prosfora ,
       comments_pro ,
       accepted ,
       onoma01 ,
       epitheto01 ,
       email01 ,
       tilefono01 ,
       weight1 ,
       depdate1 ,
       specialservices1 ,
       comments1 ,
       username01
FROM   offers ,
       registration1 ,
       customer,(SELECT startpoli_i ,
       finalpoli_i ,
       prosfora ,
       comments_pro ,
       accepted ,
       onoma01 ,
       epitheto01 ,
       email01 ,
       tilefono01 ,
       weight1 ,
       depdate1 ,
       specialservices1 ,
       comments1 ,
       username01
FROM   (offers ,registration1 ,customer)  t1
WHERE  (
              offers.string_uniq regexp concat( :str)
       AND    registration1.username01 = offers.user_i
       AND    customer.startpoli1 = offers.startpoli_i
       AND    customer.finalpoli1 = offers.finalpoli_i ))
WHERE  offers.startpoli_i = t1.startpoli_i
AND    offers.finalpoli_i = t1.finalpoli_i     ;